# generic function with binding generic variable in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, generics

can anyone explain what exactly does below generic class "Active" works with this - bind variable ? Below are 3 examples mentioned also but I'm really not clear how does it work

```
class Active<T> {

    var bind :(T) -> () = { _ in }

    var value :T {
        didSet {
            bind(value)
        }
    }

    init(_ v :T) {
        value = v
    }
}
```

Example :

1. var user = Active("")
2. var count = Active(64)
3. var status = Active(true)

Exact example shown in below link

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/2-ways-to-execute-mvvm-ios-5c47d60ebcd0

Comment: Is your issue about understanding that `bind` is a closure?

Comment: If you were to re-write that code you'd have to create 3 classes. One where all mentions of `T` are replaced with `String`. Another where all mentions of `T` are replaced with `Int`. And another where all mentions are replaced with `Bool`. Swift has Generics so can create 1 class instead of 3. `<T>` Just means any type. Anything inside `<>` is like a placeholder type. If you do `<T:Equatable>` then it just means _any_ that also happens to conform to the `Equatable` protocol. For more on that see the [docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

Comment: Side note: `didSet` shouldn't be called on `init`, so in fact the `binding` might not work as expected.

Comment: This class is a wrapper that simply calls the `bind` function whenever the value changes.

Comment: @Larme,@Honey - what does bind closure actually do??  there's nothing to  execute in closure ?

Comment: It presumes that the caller will replace the `bind` closure with something (which is why it is a `var` and not a `let`). Personally, I would have made this clear by declaring it as an optional: `var bind: ((T) -> Void)?` and the `didSet` would be `bind?(value)`.

Comment: may be something similar as per this link - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/20308. Not sure hence asking on this forum.

Comment: may be like property observers ??

Comment: @sia This uses swift property observers (the `didSet`), to provide a more flexible pattern whereby external objects can subscribe/listen for changes. Perhaps the better analogy is Combine’s `ObservableObject`. Or as that article you quote in the original question says, they’re writing their own “Observable”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with completion handlers, then this will make perfect sense to you. Consider a function with a barebones completion handler:

```
func someFunction(completion: () -> Void) {
    completion()
}

someFunction {
    print("completion")
}
```

The completion handler has no parameters and so it is called with `completion()` and the closure's capture list `someFunction { ... }` is empty. However, if we were to add a parameter to this completion handler, then it would be called with the parameter `completion(true)` and the closure would have to define its capture list `someFunction { (done) in ... }`.

```
func someFunction(completion: (_ done: Bool) -> Void) {
    completion(true)
}

someFunction { (done) in
    print(done)
}
```

And if we didn't care about the boolean in the completion handler then we could ignore it in the closure's capture list:

```
someFunction { _ in
    print("completion")
}
```

And this is what `bind` is, a closure with a single parameter with a capture list that doesn't care about the parameter it was passed.

```
var bind: (T) -> Void = { _ in }
```

So the idea is to instantiate `Active`, with a value, and then give `bind` a closure to execute whenever the value changes. And so when it changes, you have bound some task to the changing of that value.

```
// instantiate
var count = Active(64)

// bind its change to a closure
count.bind = { _ in
    // perhaps update the UI?
}

// later when the value changes, the closure is called and
// whatever task you had in the closure is executed
count.value = 128
```

And, as a side note, `T` is just an arbitrary letter (it could be ) used as a placeholder for whatever type will actually be used (i.e. `Int`, `Bool`) when this object is instantiated. Whatever `T` is, it has to be the same type throughout the use of this object.

Answer (score 1):

You give examples where you instantiate `Active` with different types of values (illustrating the generic behavior). But you are not availing yourself of the “observer” pattern that `Active` affords.

Let’s see how you would use `Active`:

```swift
let foo = Active(0)
foo.bind = { value in
    print(value)
}
foo.value = 1          // the closure will be called, printing the value
foo.value = 42         // the closure will be called again
```

The idea is that you instantiate the object, replace the `bind` closure with your own, and then the closure will be called every time you change the value.

The virtue of this “observer” pattern is that `Active` is providing a mechanism (a simple closure in this primitive example) to allow other objects to observe changes to the value. This is one of the central precepts of MVVM (as that article you quote is attempting to convey), namely, that you can write code that, for example, automatically updates a view based upon changes to a model.

Comment: thanks for explanation and example.